# Find datetime overlap with non-datetime based criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, overlap

I'm trying to determine overlap of rows based on datetime values, and am totally lost on how to accomplish this. I have a vague understanding at a high-level what needs to be done after reading replies here and other sites, but don't know where to start.

The raw data set is delimited and I'm open to doing this in Excel, Access, Python or Perl.

There are three distinct blocks of data within the larger data set (approx 115,000 rows); Apple, Orange and Pear - sample data as follows.

An image of the data set can be found at - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD3Hv.jpg

```
filename                    network     spot_id         dt_sched                dt_insert

APPLE_2012_10151135.VCA     APPLE       00NC8109450     01/01/2012 0:20:30      01/01/2012 0:23:10
APPLE_2012_10151135.VCA     APPLE       0NF81700041     01/01/2012 0:20:30      01/01/2012 0:22:40
APPLE_2012_10151135.VCA     APPLE       0NF82100170     01/01/2012 0:50:30      01/01/2012 0:48:57
APPLE_2012_10151135.VCA     APPLE       MK882000004     01/01/2012 0:50:30      01/01/2012 0:49:27
ORANGE_2012_10102135.VCA    ORANGE      0NF82100186     01/01/2012 0:15:30      01/01/2012 0:14:27
ORANGE_2012_10102135.VCA    ORANGE      00NC8139709     01/01/2012 0:15:30      01/01/2012 0:14:57
ORANGE_2012_10102135.VCA    ORANGE      0NF82400065     01/01/2012 0:31:30      01/01/2012 0:27:08
ORANGE_2012_10102135.VCA    ORANGE      000NC899740     01/01/2012 0:31:30      01/01/2012 0:27:38
ORANGE_2012_10102135.VCA    ORANGE      0NF81700041     01/01/2012 0:50:30      01/01/2012 0:46:58
ORANGE_2012_10102135.VCA    ORANGE      000NC899740     01/01/2012 0:50:30      01/01/2012 0:47:28
PEAR_2012_10125135.VCA      PEAR        0NF82100169     01/01/2012 0:15:30      01/01/2012 0:21:52
PEAR_2012_10125135.VCA      PEAR        ML817000190     01/01/2012 0:15:30      01/01/2012 0:22:22
PEAR_2012_10125135.VCA      PEAR        0NF82200043     01/01/2012 0:45:30      01/01/2012 0:47:43
PEAR_2012_10125135.VCA      PEAR        ML803000400     01/01/2012 0:45:30      01/01/2012 0:48:13
```

I need to determine on the same day if the following occurs:

Overlap between dt_sched and dt_insert

- Apple overlaps Orange
- Apple overlaps Pear
- Orange overlaps Apple
- Orange overlaps Pear
- Pear overlaps Apple
- Pear overlaps Orange

Each network in the table; Apple, Orange, Pear, contains 365 days worth of transactions and the 24 hour period for an individual day. The original data set is in Excel and I'm importing to Access.

Comment: Why not copy and paste that sample dataset into your post? A screenshot is next to useless for us to reproduce your setup.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: By "overlaps" do you mean the following: (1) in each row `dt_sched` defines the beginning of a time interval and `dt_insert` defines the end of the interval; and (2) two networks `A` and `B`  "overlap" on a given date if ANY of the intervals for network `A` overlap ANY of the intervals for network `B`?  This implies that if A overlaps B then by definition B overlaps A.

Comment: Yes, Jim. Additionally, I'm only concerned with overlaps for a single day (24 hour period) between networks A, B or C.

Comment: In the sample data, the beginning of a time interval is in places later than the end; this should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a particularly efficient way to do this.  The following gives the SQL solution:

```
select cdate(int(t1.dt_sched)) as thedate, t1.network, t2.network, count(*) as numoverlaps
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on int(t1.dt_sched) = int(t2.dt_sched) and
        t1.dt_sched <= t2.dt_insert and
        t2.dt_sched <= t1.dt_insert
group by cdate(int(t1.dt_sched)), t1.network, t2.network
```

Note:  I haven't tested this query, so it might have syntax errors.

This will determine overlaps between any two networks.  If you don't care about an overlap on the same network, include `where t1.network <> t2.network`.  If there are other networks than the ones listed, then include `where t1.network in (NETWORK LIST HERE) and t2.network in (NETWORK LIST HERE).

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. Being a SQL neophyte, I'm assuming that based on your query, you expect that the networks are in separate tables, correct? What if all the records are in a single table?

Comment: This assumes that all the records are in a single table, the way that they are described in the question.  It does not simplify the SQL if they are in a different table.

Comment: Gordon, I presume that 't' is the name of my table in your example. I attempted to run the query in Access and got a 'syntax error in FROM clause' message run executing.

 `select cdate(int(t1.dt_sched)) as thedate, t1.network, t2.network, count(*) as numoverlapsfrom small t1 join
     small t2
     on int(t1.dt_sched) = int(t2.dt_sched) and
        t1.dt_sched <= t2.dt_insert and
        t2.dt_sched <= t1.dt_insert
where t1.network <> t2.network
group by cdate(int(t1.dt_sched)), t1.network, t2.network`

Comment: The code in the comment above is missing space in `numoverlapsfrom`.